# Why does angularjs not render locally as a correct document? Please try localhost

Tags: html, angularjs

This is not working locally written as such. I just see the contents of h1 = "Your Shopping Cart"

If I add any code or brakets to full fill the error, it gives me a syntax error I do not see. I am copying from orielly book "AngularJs."

Please let me know if there are syntax errors.

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>Your Shopping Cart</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller='CartController'>
       <h1>Your Shopping Cart</h1> 
        <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
            <span>{{item.title}}</span>
            <input ng-model='item.quantity'>
            <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
            <span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency}}</span>
            <button ng-click="remove{$index}">Remove</button>
        </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function CartController($scope) {
                $scope.item = [
                    {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
                    {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
                    {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
                ];
                $scope.remove = function(index) {
                    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The issue I am now having is that ng-repeat fires and shows once then defaults to a commented out line. Please help.

This is the correct syntax:

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>Your Shopping Cart</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller='CartController'>
       <h1>Your Shopping Cart</h1> 
        <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
            <span>{{item.title}}</span>
            <input ng-model='item.quantity'>
            <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
            <span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency}}</span>
            <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
        </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function CartController($scope) {
                $scope.items = [
                    {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
                    {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
                    {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
                ];
                $scope.remove = function(index) {
                    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added the code but, getting the div ng-repeat commented out.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the braces in `ng-click="remove{$index}"` with parentheses(because it's a function call)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a two-part typo problem.

You have `$scope.item = [` but are referring to it in the rest of your code as `items`. Notice the `s` at the end. Changing it to `$scope.items = [` will solve the first problem.

You also have `ng-click="remove{$index}"` when you should be using `ng-click="remove($index)"`. Since remove is a function call parenthesis should be used.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I guess there are some syntax issues regarding this book I am reading. Thanks again, Sean.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your syntax error :

```
<button ng-click="remove{$index}">Remove</button>
```

You should instead write :

```
<button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
```

Edit : 
I'm little late to answer. as James pointed out, $scope.item should be $scope.items.

Comment: Thank you so much, answer above addressed all my issues. Cheers, Sean.